# Ajax internal server error in Symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, controller

So I have this problem with symfony 2. I get this "Internal Server Error". Below is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: resource_url + '/delete',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result){
        $(row).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
            show_msg_box('#msg-box', 'Successfully deleted <strong>' + job_name + '</strong>!');
            if(!has_table_row('.jwobs-table', 'tr.app-row')){
                $('tr.app-norow').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and this is the content of the function being called in the url

```
public function ajaxDeleteAction($job)
{
    return $this->forward('web.api.Job:deleteAction', $job);
}
```

and this is the function where the route above is being forwarded to

```
public function deleteAction($job)
{
    $con = \Propel::getConnection();

    $sql = "delete from tb_job where id = ".$job."";
    $prep = $con->prepare($sql);
    $prep->execute();

    $this->response->setStatusCode(HTTP\Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    return $this->response;
}
```

but whenever I run through this code, Im getting an Internal server error like this:

```
POST <my route here> 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send
m.extend.ajax
(anonymous function)
m.event.dispatch
r.handle
```

Im using amazon web services btw. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me.

Comment: open the url that you are trying to use in ajax call in a new tab and see it it gives you error report or something like that.

Comment: i opened it and it returned a 405 error. Its a [POST] route btw.

Comment: Open dev tools, and check preview for your ajax request.
It's hard to help when you know literally nothing.

Comment: i found the error, it seems that it was a database error. The record I am trying to delete was related to other tables with RESTRICT constraint. Thanks for the responses. Cheers